# Wildcards as method attributes in java

Tags: java, wildcard, method-parameters

Is it possible to use wildcards as an attribute itself and not as a type parameter?

```
public void doSomething(<? extends Context> myObject){


}
```

I want to make sure that my object extends Context and also implements a certain interface.

Using wildcards as a return type is valid but using it as an attribute seems to not work

```
public <? extends MyClass> validMethod(){


}
```

Comment: None of those are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you have to define it before the return type.

```
public <T extends MyClass> void myMethod(T param);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't explicitly state (for your case) which is the interface and which is the class, but if you wanted to have a generic type bound to both extending a class and an interface, this would be the general form for it.

```
public <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> T findNumber(List<T> elements) { }
```

`Number` is an abstract class; `Comparable`  is an interface.  I believe what you have to specify them in this order - concrete before interface.